# How can I compute the median absolute deviation (MAD) for generalized linear mixed-effects models

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I know my question is linked to stats but I'm looking for a solution in `R`, so I believe it's suited for SO.

I built a generalized linear mixed-effects model (GLMM) using the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package in `R` to model species richness around aquaculture sites based on significant explanatory variables using Zuur et al. (2009) *[Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441927646)*. The model is:

```
Mod1 <- glmer(Richness ~ Distance + Depth + Substrate + Beggiatoa + 
        Distance*Beggiatoa + (1|Site/transect), family = poisson, data = mydata)
```

Now I have a full data set collected at different sites and I want to assess how this model performs on the new data set.

Following a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229370/how-to-assess-glmm-performance-on-a-new-data-set) on CV, someone suggested to look for the median absolute deviation (mad) on the new data set. I tried the `mad` function from the `stats` package in `R` but I get the following error message:

```
Error in x[!is.na(x)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
2: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
```

**Does anybody knows what's going wrong here? Is it that `mad` in `stats` can't be calculated for GLMMs? If so, is there another `R` package to calculate mad from GLMMs?**

**Edit:**

To give you an idea of my data, here's the output from `dput(head(mydata))`, also note that there's no "Substrate" category in the new data set and "S" refers to "Richness":

```
structure(list(S = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2), Site = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BC", "BH", "GC", "IS", "Ref"
), class = "factor"), Transect = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("10GC", "10IS", "10N", "10S", "11IS", "12IS", 
"13E", "1GC", "1N", "1W", "2E", "2GC", "2IS", "2N", "2W", "2WA", 
"3E", "3GC", "3IS", "3N", "3S", "4E", "4GC", "4IS", "4S", "4W", 
"5GC", "5IS", "5S", "6GC", "6IS", "6N", "6S", "6W", "7E", "7GC", 
"7IS", "8GC", "8IS", "8W", "9E", "9GC", "9IS", "9N", "RefBC1", 
"RefBC10", "RefBC11", "RefBC12", "RefBC2", "RefBC3", "RefBC4", 
"RefBC5", "RefBC6", "RefBC7", "RefBC8", "RefBC9", "X1", "X2"), class = "factor"), 
Distance = c(2, 20, 40, 80, 120, 160), Depth = c(40L, 40L, 
50L, 40L, 40L, 40L), Beggiatoa = c(2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("S", 
"Site", "Transect", "Distance", "Depth", "Beggiatoa"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What does `mydata` look like? Can you post `dput(head(mydata))` to give us a sense? It sounds like R is trying to subset something that isn't a dataframe.

Comment: @jdobres Thanks for your interest. I've just updated my question with the requested information.

Comment: `mad` is meant to be used on the raw data. It accepts a numeric vector, whereas the result of `glmer` will be a list object. Also, your example data do not contain a "Richness" column.

Comment: @jdobres thanks again. "Richness" is called "S" in my data, I just spelled it out in my question for clarity. If `mad` function is only for the raw data, is there a function to calculate the median absolute deviation from `glmer` or am I trying to calculate something that can't be calculated from a `glmer`?

Comment: Please edit your question to read "How can I compute the MAD", rather than "looking for a package to ..." - SO deprecates questions that are requesting an off-site resource.  (If the *answer* turns out to be "use package xxx", that's OK.)

Comment: How do you expect to make predictions if you have Substrate in your model but don't have it available in your test data set ... ?  (There are possibilities, but they're kind of hokey -- simplest would be to leave Substrate out of the model ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Yes I'll go back to my new data set and see if I can add Substrate to it. But if not, I'll take it out of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *within-sample* error, the median absolute deviation computation would just be

```
mad(residuals(fitted_model))
```

... you might want `residuals(fitted_model,type="response")`, since `residuals` will give you deviance residuals by default (see `?residuals.merMod`)

If you want to look at *out-of-sample* error, you could do something like this:

```
pred <- predict(fitted_model,
                newdata = newdf,
                type = "response",
                re.form=~0)
mad(pred, center=newdf$S)
```

(`re.form=~0` specifies that you want to omit random effects from the prediction, which is your only choice unless you're predicting at sites/transects where you've also got training data)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and edits, that's what I was looking for. So if I understand well I would compare `mad` from the model on the **original data set** (_within-sample error_) to `mad` on the **new data set** (_out-of-sample error_), is that right?

Comment: Don't really know, haven't used MAD as a criterion very much myself.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll verify this. If you have other suggestions to assess model performance on a new data set you're more than welcome answer or comment my CV question!

Comment: does changing the `center=` in your OOS answer still return the median, or something else?